# Intellij - Hide full path in Scopes view

Tags: intellij-idea

I've started to use the Scopes view in Intelij, since the favorites got removed with the latest update (2021.3).

Somehow in the scopes view there is always the full folder path visible. In my example: below the folder `test.foo.bar.baz` there are the two folders `test.foo.bar.baz.obj1` and `test.foo.bar.baz.obj2`. I would prefer to have below the folder `test.foo.bar.baz` only the two folder `obj1` and `obj2` as in the project view.

**Scope View:**

[image: Scopes view]

**Project View:**

[image: Project view]

Is it possible to make the Scopes view look like the Project view?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Show Options Menu` (it's the cog button at the top right of the Scope View)  and disable `Tree Appearance | Flatten Packages`

Comment: You're right. I already tried this but it seems like something was broken in my .idea folder after the update. Thank you!